# second order multivariable derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, wave-equation

$ u=u(x,t)$, $x=x(x')$, $t=t(t')$

I know that
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx'}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}\frac{\partial t}{\partial x'}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dx'}$$

because $t$ is independent of $x'$

However, I don't know how to calculate $\dfrac{\partial^2u}{\partial x'^2}$

I've tried saying that

$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x'^2} =\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\bigg(\frac{dx}{dx'}\bigg)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\bigg(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg)\frac{dx}{dx'}$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x'}\bigg(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigg)\frac{dx}{dx'}$$

as $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x'}\bigg(\dfrac{dx}{dx'}\bigg)=0 $

but this leaves me with another expression I don't know how to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x'}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}
\end{eqnarray*}
Differentiating again gives
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x'^2} &=& \frac{\partial }{\partial x'} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} \right) \\
&=& \frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} + \frac{\partial }{\partial x'} \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'} \right) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \\
&=& \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial x'}\right)^2 \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}  + \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial x'^2}  \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}